# How to merge data frame in Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

I have requirement to merge two Data frame contents , dataframe A and B need C = A + B , tried with push_back() but its very very slow.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]

DataFrame mergeEx(DataFrame &dfSrcA , DataFrame &dfSrcB)

{

    Rcpp::IntegerVector   col = dfSrcA["A1"];

    Rcpp::IntegerVector   col1   = dfSrcA["A2"];

    Rcpp::IntegerVector   Bcol  = dfSrcB["A1"];
    Rcpp::IntegerVector   Bcol1 = dfSrcB["A2"];


//  col.push_back(7);

  //col.push_back(8);
  //col1.push_back(9);
  //col1.push_back(10);

  //return DataFrame::create(l,l1);
    return DataFrame::create(Named("A1") = col, Named("A2") = col1);

}
```

tried with std::copy() as in below function but getting error

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]

DataFrame mergeEx(DataFrame &dfSrcA , DataFrame &dfSrcB)

{

    Rcpp::IntegerVector   col = dfSrcA["A1"];

    Rcpp::IntegerVector   col1   = dfSrcA["A2"];

    Rcpp::IntegerVector   Bcol  = dfSrcB["A1"];
    Rcpp::IntegerVector   Bcol1 = dfSrcB["A2"];

    long lsize = col.size();

    std::copy(Bcol.begin(),Bcol.end(),col.begin()+lsize);

    lsize=col1.size();

    std::copy(Bcol1.begin(),Bcol1.end(),col1.begin()+lsize);

    return DataFrame::create(Named("A1") = col, Named("A2") = col1); 

}
```

C=mergeEx(A,B)

getting below error
Error in mergeEx(A, B, C) : 
  could not convert using R function : as.data.frame

Request your help to suggest fastest way to merge two dataframes using Rcpp as soon as possible, i am looking out speed as latency is concerned in merging these two data frames in R.

Also suggest me with good documentation link on dataframe , documents i found providing very basic information.